# Excel to vb.net in real time

Tags: vb.net, excel, dde

I am facing the following problems:

I am updating data into Excel in Real Time with an 3rd party software, when i try to get the data from Excel to vb.net(to a TextBox), the TextBox is not updating, it is showing only first value after that it is not updating the same data which is updating in real time as in Excel, I request you to provide me an solution for this, if possible please provide me an an example program.

thank you sir

Comment: Please show the code you have so far to load the text box and for updating it.

Comment: please visit [ask] and [mcve]